# avoid alert Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-chrome, xss

How I can prevent chrome throws  error: **Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found Within request.**
This occurs because my html code contains objects that launch one function when mousedown occurs,for example:

```
<div>
<?php
    echo "<span onmousedown=\"myfunction();\"> example </span>";
    echo "<span onmousedown='myfunction();'> example 2 </span>";

?>
</div>
```

The error occurs when redirected to the same page, however not the case when I first entered on the page or when it reloaded the page.
I do not want to disable the  **X-XSS-Protection** ,I need a more elegant solution. A solution with code: php, html or javascript

***I try to make a legitimate use of the function, not trying to inject script***

Comment: Why is the source in the request? What's the querystring / POST body?

Comment: That's invalid PHP anyways. No idea how you could even get chrome to spit out an error because PHP should have barfed on that first.

Comment: As an aside, don't use [PHP short open tags](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Good advice, but what is the difference? ¿better performance is obtained or is a matter of design?

Comment: The post elaborates, but essential design + more compatible code.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div>
<?php
echo "<span onmousedown='myfunction();'> example </span>"

?>
</div>
```

Notice single quote arriund myfunction()